# Should I reply to interview emails with unspecified dates?

Tags: interviewing, email-etiquette

I recently applied for a job and after two weeks I got an email in which the manager wrote:

> Due to internal repositioning of staffs we couldn’t get back to you
> earlier, but you can expect to be invited to an interview soon.

Should I reply to this email with a simple *“Thanks, I am looking forward to …”*, as in like thank you, sure, I am still interested?
I personally think that it would be waste of the manager’s time having to open and read these kinds of emails since he soon would send an actual invitation email.
I am in doubt because a little before that, another manager from another company sent me *“a little technical test”* before I was supposed to be invited for an interview. I didn’t reply to that email, I just completed the task and replied to that email with my solution to the test. After that, I did not hear from that manager/company. I sent another email to the manager respectfully *“asking for feedback”* which he did not respond to. That’s why I am in doubt whether I should reply to this new email or not.

Comment: Either way is fine. You can either reply to his email or choose not to. A brief reply such as  “Thanks, I am looking forward to …” does not hurt.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes - They are trying to find out if still interested.

Further emails with give some options on dates/times that they are available.

If able, choose the earliest.

As the saying goes *The earliest bird catches the worm*.

Answer (score 3):

> Should I reply to this email with a simple “Thanks, I am looking
> forward to …”, as in like thank you, sure, I am still interested?

Yes.

If they read it then you've signaled your continuing interest in the position. If they don't read it then there's no harm done in sending it.